Bigquery API fails to deploy in google Run
I want to deploy a Dash (of Flask) App in Google Cloud Run.
The input data would come from a BigQuery table.
So I use the BigQuery python API.
The App works fine locally and I can deploy it to Cloud Run,
but on Cloud Run  I only get the response Service Unavailable.
The console shows Error 503.
To give a minimalist exemple of the problem,  I start from here : https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy/deploy-python-service
I only added the code :
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client()  
query = "SELECT * from `sucombe.prestaProduit.prestaProd2024`  limit 5"
df=client.query(query).to_dataframe()
print(df[:5])

In requirements.txt, I added :
pandas
google-cloud-bigquery

Does someone know how to make it work ?
Thanks

Have you checked the logs for the cloud run service in stackdriver?

I have tried to read différent logs but I have no knowledge of stackdriver. I think the problem is coming from .to_dataframe(). It does not belong to bigquery or pandas modules.
